# DjangoRestFramework - object level permission not being allowed for some reason (has_permission and has_object_permission)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

This is my permission:

```
class IsFllowOrAdminUserOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Allow any users to follow objects and ReadOnly. Allow all requests for
    admin users.
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS or request.user.is_staff

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Allow watching objects.
        if view.action=='follow':
            return True

        return request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS or request.user.is_staff
```

And this is my viewset (and follow action):

```
class PageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsCreationOrFollowOrOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, location=self.request.user.userextended.location)

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def follow(self, request, pk=None):
        page = self.get_object()    

        page.users.add(request.user)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

The problem is, when an authenticated user tries to follow an object, it gives me a `403_FORBIDDEN` error even though I have the code:

```
if view.action=='follow':
    return True
```

Any idea how I should fix this?

Note that this issue is different than this one I posted earlier: [DjangoRestFramework - How to properly seperate has_permission and has_object_permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468455/djangorestframework-how-to-properly-seperate-has-permission-and-has-object-per) because this permission only allows admin users to create objects whereas the other post allows any users to create objects.

Comment: Try commenting out `has_permission` and see if it still complains.

Answer (score 1):

A `detail_route` request or `POST` request won't reach the `has_object_permission`. Only `PUT, PATCH, DELETE` will reach  `has_object_permission`

So try:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and view.action=='follow':
        return True
    return request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS or request.user.is_staff

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    return request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS or request.user.is_staff
```

this will allow:

- unauthenticated users to readonly
- authenticated users to readonly & `follow`
- admin can perform any request

Comment: The issue with the code you posted is that by removing `has_permission`, any users are now allowed to make POST requests to create objects, which I don't want.